# Add a div at the bottom of the header in PrimeNG and DataView

Tags: css, angular, primeng

In my Angular 8 app I have a PrimeNG DataView element. In this element, simple I would add a row with the name of the fields at the bottom of the header.

So, I tried to add a `<div>` tag in every possible position of the html code of this component to understand how to do and: or this tag was too hight (it was visible, but not at the bottom of the header, but i.e. between search row and paginator row), or it was hidden. It was impossible to me, add a div tag in correct position, making this div visible.

I attach an image (please, consider the only point 1) and the code.

```
<p-header>
            <div class="ui-helper-clearfix">
                <div class="ui-g">
                    <div class="ui-g-12 ui-md-4">
                        <p-dropdown [options]="sortOptions" [(ngModel)]="sortKey" placeholder="Sort By" (onChange)="onSortChange($event)" [style]="{'min-width':'140px'}"></p-dropdown>
                    </div>
                    <div class="ui-g-6 ui-md-4 filter-container">
                        <div style="position:relative">
                            <input type="search" pInputText placeholder="Search by brand" (input)="dv.filter($event.target.value)">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="ui-g-6 ui-md-4" style="text-align:right">
                        <p-dataViewLayoutOptions></p-dataViewLayoutOptions>
                    </div>
                </div>
            <!-- A div at this exact position is visibile but is not at the bottom of header -->
            </div>
        <!-- A div at this exact position, maybe the better and more logic one, is unvisible -->
        </p-header>
        <!-- End of the header, start of data row; a div at this exact position is unvisible --> 
        <ng-template let-person pTemplate="listItem">
            <div class="ui-g-12">
                <div class="car-details">
                    <div>
                        <div class="ui-g">
                            <div class="ui-g-12">Vin: <b>{{person.id}}</b></div>
                            <div class="ui-g-12">Year: <b>{{person.name}}</b></div>
                            <div class="ui-g-12">Brand: <b>{{person.surname}}</b></div>
                            <div class="ui-g-12">Color: <b>{{person.officeNumber}}</b></div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <button pButton type="button" icon="pi pi-search" (click)="selectPerson($event, person)"></button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </ng-template>
```

[image]

Comment: Please note that when entering HTML tags like `<div>`, they need to be surrounded in backticks in order to be visible in posts. Always use the preview window to ensure your post will appear correctly before submitting it.

Answer (score 0):

As per my understanding from your question, I have added a row for you. Please see the screenshot for reference. For your convenience I have highlighted in `lightblue` background color.

[image]

To Achieve this:  **In your component.html** Please see the `lorem` block

```
<p-dataView
    #dv
    [value]="cars"
    [paginator]="true"
    [rows]="20"
    paginatorPosition="both"
    filterBy="brand"
    [sortField]="sortField"
    [sortOrder]="sortOrder"
>
    <p-header>
        <div class="ui-helper-clearfix">
            <div class="ui-g">
                <div class="ui-g-12 ui-md-4">
                    <p-dropdown
                        [options]="sortOptions"
                        [(ngModel)]="sortKey"
                        placeholder="Sort By"
                        (onChange)="onSortChange($event)"
                        [style]="{ 'min-width': '140px' }"
                    ></p-dropdown>
                </div>
                <div class="ui-g-6 ui-md-4 filter-container">
                    <div style="position:relative">
                        <input
                            type="search"
                            pInputText
                            placeholder="Search by brand"
                            (input)="dv.filter($event.target.value)"
                        />
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="ui-g-6 ui-md-4" style="text-align:right">
                    <p-dataViewLayoutOptions></p-dataViewLayoutOptions>
                </div>
                <div class="ui-g white-bg">
                    <div class="ui-g-6 ui-md-4">
                        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing
                        elit. Accusamus cupiditate dolores esse id ipsam omnis
                        reiciendis repellat, temporibus voluptas? Consequuntur
                        dolor inventore natus, porro quis tempore veniam.
                        Consectetur consequatur deleniti esse ex molestiae rem
                        sed temporibus voluptates! Ad aliquam, aspernatur cum
                        cumque fugiat harum ipsa, ipsam laudantium modi nemo
                        perferendis perspiciatis quis, quos rerum veritatis?
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </p-header>
```

Step 2: In your component.css:

```
:host ::ng-deep {
    .white-bg {
        background-color: lightskyblue;
    }
}
```

You can follow the same approach if you want to display the row below the pagination.

Comment: No. The main point problem it self is make a div BELOW the pagination, not add a div. If I follow your post, I see the div before the pagination. What do you means by "following the same approach"? I have already tried to put a div in all possible position but if the div is below the pagination div it not appears. Other idea? Thank you very much!

Comment: @Archimede sorry quite unclear. So you want div below the pagination ? what do you mean no add a div but make div

Comment: Thank for your reply and sorry if unclear. No add a div, but add a div below pagination. The problem is not "how add a div", but "how add a div right under pagination". See please my original image: there is the red area I want to add exactly in the position I want. If you need other infos, I am here. Thank.